# Android sip without SIP server

Tags: android, sip

I have been trying to develop an android sip client that connects through specifying the ip addresses of the devices involved.

Is it possible to make a peer-to-peer SIP call on android , without a SIP server registration ?

Comment: Its not possible. you have to create a sip account.

Comment: I got it to work in P2P with Android 4.4.4 and an Nexus 4 - however the same source does not work on an Nexus 5 running 4.4.4 too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though i could not do this using android APIs , Found an opensource which worked well on android phone. I was able to make a direct call within the local network, by specifying the IP of the other person.

http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/guide/

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The SIP protocol does not prohibit peer-to-peer communications. In fact, the SIP protocol abstracts SIP Proxies and Registrars and does not define actual communication topology, outside of this implementation. In this scenario (peer-to-peer), you would not REGISTER any SIP UAC clients, instead each SIP UAC would implement it's own SIP Proxy (i.e. UAC+UAS, SIP Proxy listening on SIP ports).  Client "A" would then simply send INVITE to Client "B" to initiate a a phone call.